# Read original document from signed PDF with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, certificate, digital-signature, pdfbox

I need to know i the signature on a PDF document is put on the document that the software generated and that the document has not been manipulated.

I was trying to obtain the original document from the PDF using PDFBox so I got to this point:

```
public static List<PDFSignatureInfo> getPDFSignatureInfo(byte[] byteArray ) throws IOException, CertificateException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException,
        NoSuchProviderException, SignatureException, InvalidNameException, TSPException {

    List<PDFSignatureInfo> lpsi = new ArrayList<PDFSignatureInfo>();

    // Try to open the input file as PDF
    try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray))) {
        // Get Signature dictionaries of PDF
        for (PDSignature sig : document.getSignatureDictionaries()) {
            PDFSignatureInfo psi = new PDFSignatureInfo();
            lpsi.add(psi);

            COSDictionary sigDict = sig.getCOSObject();
            COSString contents = (COSString) sigDict.getDictionaryObject(COSName.CONTENTS);

            Set<Map.Entry<COSName, COSBase>> entries = sigDict.entrySet();
            for(Map.Entry<COSName, COSBase> entry: entries) {
                // Don't return contents
                if(!entry.getKey().equals(COSName.CONTENTS)) {
                    psi.entries.put(entry.getKey().getName(), entry.getValue().toString());
                }
            }

            psi.reason = sig.getReason();
            psi.name = sig.getName();
            psi.signDate = sig.getSignDate().getTime();
            psi.subFilter= sig.getSubFilter();
            psi.contactInfo = sig.getContactInfo();
            psi.filter = sig.getFilter();
            psi.location = sig.getLocation();

            psi.signedContent = sig.getSignedContent(byteArray);
```

I'm creating a list of PDFSignatureInfo objects, a model that I'd like to use. Now I thought that what I'm obtaining with the last line written above was the `byte[]` containing the original document. But when compared to the original document, it's not the same (probably there are obvious reasons that are not obvious for me.)

Any help?

Comment: The ShowSignature.java example from the source code download has a verification that does just that, i.e. verify that the document has not been manipulated. Getting the original document, there is no API... one would have to search for the last EOF within the first byte range of the signature. This would work for PDFBox, I don't know if it works for all PDF files. I believe I once saw a PDF that had a signature without using incremental save.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of the above mentioned question because even though it mentions a different pdf library, the answer is not pdf library specific.

Comment: *"I believe I once saw a PDF that had a signature without using incremental save."* - indeed, unless the original pdf already is signed (e.g. with a certification signature), the process of signing does not need to keep a byte-by-byte equal copy of the original pdf, merely a set of equivalent pdf objects. Thus, in general your task is very difficult to implement (as testing for such an "equivalent set" is non-trivial). But if your original already is signed, the test becomes doable.

Comment: @mkl So if I generate the document and sign it by the software before giving it to the user, the following signatures are added in append mode so that would let me make some comparison?

Comment: Yes, at least if the user does not manipulate the document by removing your signature before signing himself (but that would be a case you want to recognize anyways, a user manipulating the document before signing), and also assuming the user's signing app is not broken.

Comment: @mkl ok that is fantastic! :) thanks